# Qanteda textplot_scale1d() is not working

Tags: r, text, quanteda

```html
library(quanteda)
library(quanteda.textmodels)
```

```html
# Transform corpus to dfm
data(data_corpus_irishbudget2010, package = "quanteda.textmodels")
ie_dfm <- dfm(tokens(data_corpus_irishbudget2010))

# Set reference scores
refscores <- c(rep(NA, 4), 1, -1, rep(NA, 8))

# Predict Wordscores model
ws <- textmodel_wordscores(ie_dfm, y = refscores, smooth = 1)

# Plot estimated word positions (highlight words and print them in red)
textplot_scale1d(ws,
                 highlighted = c("minister", "have", "our", "budget"), 
                 highlighted_color = "red")
```

Error in textplot_scale1d(ws, highlighted = c("minister", "have", "our",  :
could not find function "textplot_scale1d"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `library("quanteda.textplots")` to the top, since that package contains the function `textplot_scale1d()`.